# Insert values to Sql database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to keep the Date in String format in a database but it always returns me -1. 
why is it happening?

```
public boolean addDate(String item1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, item1);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the DataBaseHelper class -

```
package com.exemple.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Mitch on 2016-05-13.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "Date";
    public static final String COL2 = "Distance";
    public static final String COL3 = "Time";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " ITEM1 TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addDate(String item1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, item1);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public boolean addDis(String item1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item1);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public boolean addTime(String item1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL3, item1);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getListContents(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here. What are the values of `COL1` and `item1`? Can you show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement so we know what your table is supposed to look like?

Comment: please have a look at my update

Comment: Never use `insert()`; replace it with `insertOrThrow()`.

Comment: what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a column called `Date` in your table (nor `Distance` or `Time` for that matter). You'll need to change your `CREATE TABLE` statement to include these columns:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME 
        + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
        + COL1 + " TEXT, "
        + COL2 + " TEXT, "
        + COL3 + " TEXT, "
        + "ITEM1 TEXT)";
```

This is assuming that all the columns will be of type `TEXT` and that you still need the column `ITEM1`. If not, then just delete that line and close the bracket after `COL3`.

Answer (score 1):

it's becuase you are using `COL1` as key but equals to `="Date"` but table `mylist_data` contains only one column named `"ITEM1"` so please replace `COL1 = "Date"` to `"ITEM1"`.

Comment: Be sure to use correct quotes. In Java, `'`' is only used for single characters.

Comment: I couldn't understand so good what do you mean would you like to please show me the changes in the code?

Comment: Please replace follow line

    public static final String COL1 = "Date" to       public static final String COL1 = "ITEM1";

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do this the opposite way round in this case? I.e. change `ITEM1` to `Date` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, to make the table more easily understandable? And with this answer, OP would still be missing the correct columns for the `addDis()` and `addTime()` methods.